# JBOSS 6.3 Access log auto deletion

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I am looking for a solution in JBOSS EAP 6.3 for the automatic deletion of access logs. I have added the below configuration to get the access logs printed in a different file but it doesn't have any parameter to delete the files after a specific interval.

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %S %T" prefix="access_log_" rotate="true">
    <directory path="." />
</access-log>
```

Answer (score -1):

In standalone.xml , you  can have log handler configuration  based on the size.

```
  <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <rotate-size value="1M"/>
                <max-backup-index value="1"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </size-rotating-file-handler>
```

Comment: I don't think the above works for access logs.

Comment: You might have to customize it by changing name, path etc. This  is what i am using in 7.4 .  Please check this detailed link from red hat. There is  a periodic log handler as well which can help to configure hourly .
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sample_xml_configuration_for_a_periodic_log_handler1

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sample_xml_configuration_for_a_size_log_handler1